# Using MyFaces CODI with JBoss 7

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, jboss-weld, codi

I was using JBoss 7 with JSF 2.0 (Mojarra) and Weld as CDI. Everything that JBoss already provides. Also, I added Primefaces to the package. So by now, my project is:

JBoss 7 + JSF 2.0 + Primefaces + Weld

However, I was feeling that JSF ViewScope was missing on Weld (and on CDI), so I just added MyFaces CODI to my project. But I'm feeling that I'm mixing lots of stuff right now, and I don't know what is what. So I have a few questions:

1 - Adding MyFaces CODI to the project is only CDI, or I'm changing Mojarra also?

2 - Adding MyFaces CODI also invalidate Weld, or I'm using CODI for the ViewScope and Weld for the others (Request, Application, Session, etc)? Is this a good idea?

Hope you understand my question and help me =P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Adding MyFaces CODI to the project is only CDI, or I'm changing Mojarra also?*

You're not changing Mojarra. CODI is just an extension to CDI.

---

> *Adding MyFaces CODI also invalidate Weld, or I'm using CODI for the ViewScope and Weld for the others (Request, Application, Session, etc)?*

You're not changing Weld. CODI is just an extension to CDI.

Comment: Balus, thanks. About Weld and CODI, weld will be dealing with all cdi, and CODI just adds some stuff to it, is that right?